# asp .net jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am new to asp .net. I am trying to use the JQuery library scripts. So included them in my aspx page as follows

```
<script src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/jquery-1.3.2.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/jquery.validate.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/jquery.form.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I just wrote the sample code to test the alert message.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('hi');
    });
</script>
```

I did not get any error when the page loaded but the alert message is not displayed. I hope I have got all the files necessary for using jquery. But I dont know why the alert message does not display. Any thoughts or comments?

Comment: What does the script src tag resolve to in the HTML? Is the location correct? Are the JS files indeed in the root of the site?

Comment: The view source shows up as follows

<script src="jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


The scripts in the solution where located in this order:
root/scripts/jquery/jqueryfiles.js




Additionally it gave a javscript error that says $ is not defined. I hope it doesn't even conidered the scripts that I added.

Comment: Version 1.4.2 is the currently the latest. And you can use a tool like HttpWatch to see if your scripts are being loaded.

Comment: you probably need to change your Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/jquery-1.3.2.js") to Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/scripts/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.js")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following then for each file:

```
<script src='<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/scripts/jquery/a-jquery-file.js")%>' 
   type='text/javascript'></script>
```

`~/` indicates the root of the folder, so you need the additional folder structure.